# Fetch azure block blob using eTag

Tags: node.js, azure-blob-storage

I wish to retrieve a specific block blob from Azure storage account. Can I use eTag? How can it be done using Node JS? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything to fetch a specific blob without using the getURL method.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ETag is not a static property like an ID would be- it is used to manage concurrent
updates. Every time a blob is updated the ETag is changed.

The URL is what acts as a unique, static identifier for a given blob- that is why it is used in the [API/SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) to fetch a given blob.